# How to import referenced files in ETL scripts?

Tags: pyspark, aws-glue

I have a script which I'd like to pass a configuration file into. On the Glue jobs page, I see that there is a "Referenced files path" which points to my configuration file. How do I then use that file within my ETL script?

I've tried `from configuration import *`, where the referenced file name is `configuration.py`, but no luck (ImportError: No module named configuration).

Comment: I haven't found a way that integrates in the way that glue probably intends, but for now using `sc.addPyFile('s3://bucket/path/to/file.py')` is working well for me.

Answer (score 4):

I noticed the same issue. I believe there is already a ticket to address it, but here is what AWS support suggests in the meantime.

> If you are using **referenced files path** variable in a **Python
>   shell** job, referenced file is found in `/tmp`, where Python shell
>   job has no access by default. However, the same operation works
>   successfully in Spark job, because the file is found in the default
>   file directory.

Code below helps find the absolute path of `sample_config.json` that was referenced in Glue job configuration and prints its contents.

```
import json
import sys, os

def get_referenced_filepath(file_name, matchFunc=os.path.isfile):
    for dir_name in sys.path:
        candidate = os.path.join(dir_name, file_name)
        if matchFunc(candidate):
            return candidate
    raise Exception("Can't find file: ".format(file_name))

with open(get_referenced_filepath('sample_config.json'), "r") as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    print(data)
```

Boto3 API can be used to access the referenced file as well

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
obj = s3.Object('sample_bucket', 'sample_config.json')
for line in obj.get()['Body']._raw_stream:
    print(line)
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue with a Glue v2 **Spark** job, rather than a **Python shell** job which the other answer discusses in detail.

The AWS documentation says that it is not necessary to zip a single `.py` file. However, I decided to use a `.zip` file anyway.

My `.zip` file contains the following:

```
Archive:  utils.zip
 Length   Method    Size  Cmpr    Date    Time   CRC-32   Name
--------  ------  ------- ---- ---------- ----- --------  ----
       0  Defl:N        5   0% 01-01-2049 00:00 00000000  __init__.py
    6603  Defl:N     1676  75% 01-01-2049 00:00 f4551ccb  utils.py
--------          -------  ---                            -------
    6603             1681  75%                            2 files
```

Note that `__init__.py` is present and the archive is compressed using Deflate (usual zip format).

In my Glue Job, I added the **referenced files path** job parameter pointing to my zip file on S3.

In the job script, I needed to explicitly add my zip file to the Python path before the import would work.

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "utils.zip")

import utils
```

Failing to do the above resulted in a `ImportError: No module named` error.

For others who are struggling with this, inspecting the following variables helped me to debug the issue and arrive at the solution. Paste into your Glue job and view the results in Cloudwatch.

```
import sys
import os

print(f"os.getcwd()={os.getcwd()}")
print(f"os.listdir('.')={os.listdir('.')}")
print(f"sys.path={sys.path}")
```