# How to replace values of parameters in AWS Glue job from an s3 file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

My requirement is that I have a variable "ID" whose value changes for every environment, so I want to store the value in a seperate file and use the parameter(similar to informatica mapping) ID or $$ID in the AWS Glue job.
Can glue read the file and take the value of ID and replace it in Glue job ? If yes please let me know how i can achieve this. something like
below

df_bu.bu_id="100102102221" ( this value changes in every environment) so instead of editing the script in every environment i want to store the value in a file and use

df_bu.bu_id= "$$id" ( or somthing like this, and glue job while running the script should search the file for value of $$id and replace the value in the script)

I hope i made my requirement clear. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this out - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68661438/glue-etl-how-to-reference-config-file-as-extra-file-using-aws-management-consol/

Comment: Thank you @RohitPahuja, I tried the below