# AWS Glue - Read a 'local' file in Python

Tags: python, aws-glue

In AWS Glue I use a legacy Python package that reads a constant json file from the same package. To simplify things, let's say `testLib` package has a `test_lib.py` and `data.json` files. `test_lib.py` has a function:

```
def test():
    f = open('data.json')
```

I uploaded testLib.zip to S3 and use it in the AWS Glue job:

```
from test_lib import test

test()
```

The AWS Glue job fails with the error: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data.json'`
There are many questions about how to manage files on S3 in AWS Glue. But it requires changing the legacy package that I don't want to do.
Is there any way to configure AWS Glue job to allow open 'local' files?

Comment: this might help with understanding Glue directory structure - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48596627/how-to-import-referenced-files-in-etl-scripts/58398179#58398179